# Find last used cell in a specific column and border around with a range

Tags: excel, vba, border

I have this Excel with values starting from **K3** (users put their values starting from that cell, so I don't know how much would be long **Row 3**) and I would like to border around from **K3** to last value in that row(**Row3**) and from **Row10** to last value that was used in **Row3**(sorry I really don't know how to say it, I will put an Example to let you understand better)

Here is a picture

[image]

The only code I found is this, but it's working only with static range.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("K3:P10")

    With rng.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Would this have to be dynamic? I mean: should these borders change "live" when users enter/delete data from row 3?

Comment: @JvdV No, I was only making a macro to make users border around. If they want they will take delete, values and borders and start over again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your sheet name
        LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'this will find the last used column on Row 3
        Set rng = Range("K3", .Cells(10, LastCol))
    End With

    With rng
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks to me OP want to input data in columns, not rows ;)

Comment: True that... thought he was getting confused... And I was :/ Thanks @JvdV, I've edited my answer

Comment: @SometingNew try now, I was confused and was calculating the last row, now it's calculating the last column.

Comment: Yes sorry Damian I know my question was not clear, cheers... Can I ask another thing? It works, but It borders my all my cells, could you make it border only around? Like in image?

Comment: @SometingNew there you have my edit. I bet there's a cleaner way but I don't know how to make it cleaner, sorry ^^

Comment: You can simply apply `.BorderAround`

Comment: @Damian If I can ask you a last question... If the last used cell is Merged?

Comment: @Damian Or I should ask another question on StackOverflow for the last merged cell? Sorry Im still improving

Comment: @SometingNew use an `If` statement, `If .Cells(3, LastCol).MergeArea.Columns.Count > 1 Then LastCol = LastCol + .Cells(3, LastCol).MergeArea.Columns.Count  - 1` just after calculating the `LastCol`

Answer (score 4):

Just an example for dynamic input (which can be improved upon):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim lc As Long

If Not Intersect(Range("3:3"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    lc = Range("K3").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count 'No xlToLeft just in case far to the right there might be other cells
    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(3, 11), Cells(10, 11 + lc))
    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(3, 11), Cells(10, 11 + lc - 1))
    rng1.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    rng2.BorderAround ColorIndex:=1
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image]

So far this will only work when adding/deleting per column...As mentioned, it can be improved upon ;)

Comment: Wow! this is another level Excel! JvdV you are a Pro!

Comment: I certainly am not ;)